# Receiving permission denied when using sudo

Tags: shell-script, permissions, sudo

I have added the following single line to `/etc/sudoers` via command `visudo`:

`www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/db_backup.sh`

Upon executing the command as `www-data` via:

`sudo -u www-data /var/www/db_backup.sh`

I receive the following message:

`sudo: unable to execute /var/www/db_backup.sh: Permission denied`

Unsure why this would be as I have used this same procedure in the past without issue. There must be something I am overlooking. Does anything point out to anyone. My `/etc/sudoers` file is listed below:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL


www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/db_backup.sh



# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Also as a side note when attempting to run the command `sudo /var/www/db_backup.sh` from within a php process running under www-data the following message is received (although I gather that's just from the issue with the permissions not being picked up from the sudoers file?):

`sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

**EDIT**

`ls -al /var/www/db_backup.sh`

yields the following result:

`-rwxrwx--- 1 root root 523 Jan  7  2019 /var/www/db_backup.sh`

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -al /var/www/db_backup.sh` .

Comment: @schaiba Question has been updated.

Comment: @Christopher so even though the user has sudo access to run the file with root permissions, it still needs to have executable permissions to that file?

Comment: @Christopher the script runs several root level commands that are executed when a specific php script is invoked via nginx (custom code deployment script). The purpose of the shell script is to allow www-data sudo permissions to execute that file instead of giving www-data access to those commands.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, your script is not executable by other users. So, as mentioned, change user ownership and group ownership, then mark it as executable : `chown www-data:www-data /var/www/db_backup.sh && chmod +x /var/www/db_backup.sh` . Regarding your second problem, it should be asked separately, but anyway, without knowing exactly what the script contains, it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: So just to confirm, if you grant a user sudo access via sudoers, that user also must have execute permissions on that script?

Comment: yes, that is correct. two different things.

Comment: This allows the script to execute, but when it attempts to execute commands inside of the script that require root privilege, they all fail. Which points me back to the configuration of /etc/sudoers not being read/loaded correctly.

Comment: the config is loaded correctly. your `NOPASSWD` line in `/etc/sudoers` allows the script to execute via `sudo`, NOT the commands inside it.

Comment: I appreciate the response, however I managed to get this working again and am now really confused! If the behavior you have described above is correct, what I have configured cannot be working, yet it is. I have described the issue within another post as it does not directly relate to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553631

Comment: @schaiba The user running the `sudo` command does not need execute permissions on the script, only the user that you're changing to (e.g. `www-data`) needs execute.